# Erro ao usar dynamic em C#

Tags: c#

Fiz uma aplicação em C# e para integrar com o ERP Primavera e passei o motor no VBA através da seguinte linha.

```
void IPublicMethods.UpdateCDU_IfItemSelected(ref dynamic doc, string artigo, int numLinha, ref dynamic plataformaPri, ref dynamic BSO)
{
    //Variable to tell if a document must set the CDUs for MoedaRef
    bool usaMoedaRef = false;

    try
    {
        //Get the value from DocumentosVanda table that tell if the current document must set the CDUs for MoedaRef
        plataformaPri.Dialogos.MostraAviso("Chegei!", Enums.PRI_Informativo, $"Cheguei antes do erro.");
        usaMoedaRef = BSO.Comercial.TabVendas.DaValorAtributo(doc.Tipodoc, "CDU_UsaMoedaRef");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        plataformaPri.Dialogos.MostraAviso("Erro!", Enums.PRI_Informativo, $"Ocorreu um erro ao calcular os preços {ex.Message}.");
     }        
}
```

E o VBA está assim

```
    OpsMoedaRef.updateCDU_IfItemSelected Me.DocumentoVenda, artigo, numLinha, PlataformaPRIMAVERA, BSO
```

O erro.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde é que ele dá o erro exatamente? Já colocou algum _breakpoint_ para perceber onde pára?

Comment: E precisa mesmo fazer isto? Parece que você sabe o tipo que vai receber. De qualquer forma não parece ser ele o responsável pelo erro. Capturar exceção assim é horrível em C#, sei lá se esse ERP obriga fazer essa atrocidade.

Comment: @acamiloMoz: Não te esqueças de marcar as respostas que te ajudam como validas :)

Comment: João Martins O erro esta ocorre na linha seguinte usaMoedaRef = BSO.Comercial.TabVendas.DaValorAtributo(doc.Tipodoc, "CDU_UsaMoedaRef");
 pois em tempo de execução não é reconhecido TabVendas como propriedade ou método do objecto BSO.Comercial.

Comment: Talvez o motor _Comercial_ não esteja corretamente instanciado. Se seguir as indicações do @SérgioSereno não consegue ter isso funcional?

Comment: Boas, o VBA não funciona bem com dynamic, mas se usares Object em vez de dynamic o vba papa bem

Comment: @DavidFerreira ué, e eu achando que o `dynamic` tinha sido criado principalmente para interoperar com VBA e coisas do tipo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bem a abordagem que sigo é esta:

Criar um interface que te permite expor no mundo COM as propriedades que queres passar para .NET. Importar são as metatags que estã no incio `ComVisible` e `[Guid("")]`. São elas que te vão permitir ver isto no VBA.

O Guid deves gerar um novo.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Interop.ErpBS900;

namespace Primavera.Extensibility
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("93C76FF4-D300-4BD9-911C-6A7BEBD648B2")]
    public interface IHostWindow
    {
        void AntesDeGravar(Boolean Cancel);

        ErpBS Motor { set; }

    }
}
```

Depois crias uma classe concreta que implementa essa interfaçe:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Interop.ErpBS900;

namespace Primavera.Extensibility
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("83F0D3D1-0B17-4453-852E-7CAA470B72AB")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class CustomerVBA : IHostWindow
    {
        #region internal

        internal ErpBS bso;

        #endregion     

        #region VBA Members

        public ErpBSMotor
        {
            set
            {
                bso = value;
            }

            get
            {
                return bso;
            }
        }

        public void AntesDeGravar(bool Cancel)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(BSO.Comercial.TabVendas.DaValorAtributo("FA", "descricao"));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Por fim mas propriedades do projeto marcar esta flag.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa Sereno estou seguindo a mesma abordagem o que está a acontecer é que a propriedade TabVendas não é reconhecida como membro do comercial.  BSO.Comercial.TabVendas.DaValorAtributo

Comment: Se seguires o exemplo que te dei não funciona? Tenho isso a funcionar assim.

Comment: Estava a agora a criar um pequeno projecto para simular e dá na mesma. o erro  'System.__ComObject' does not contain a definition for 'TabVendas'.

Comment: Bem o problema está no dynamic. Usa as referencias aos objectos e tudo vai funcionar. Atualizei o exemplo acima

Comment: Com os interops fucionou bem.

Comment: Agora estou tendo outro desafio. Estou actualizando o preço unitário das linhas no editos de Vendas e gostaria de actualizar o campo com um número negativo e ele apenas é assumido como positivo. ex: Artigo.PrecoUnit = -1*20   o resultado é mostrado sempre na linha 20.

Comment: @acamiloMoz Coloca outra questão com essa duvida. Cada questão neste fórum deve ser apenas de um problema especifico.